# Ресивер. Указатель или значение

Tags: классы, golang, методы

Привет. Возник вопрос. Разбираюсь с go и в примере с реализацией методов, приводится следующий пример:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type rect struct {
    width, height int
}

func (self rect) area() int {
    return self.height * self.width
}

func (self *rect) perim() int {
    return 2 * (self.height + self.width)
}

func main() {
    obj := new(rect)

    obj.width = 2
    obj.height = 6

    fmt.Println(obj.area())
    fmt.Println(obj.perim())


    rp := &obj
    fmt.Println("area: ", (*rp).area())
    fmt.Println("perim:", (*rp).perim())
}
```

Реализуется 2 метода. В одном используется указатель в качестве ресивера. В другом -- значение. В чём принципиальное отличие? Пожалуйста, приведите пример, из которого будет ясно, что происходит в одном случае, что -- в другом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принципиальное различие в том, что для ресивера по значению происходит копирование объекта, в то время как для ресивера по указателю передается указатель. Для встроенных или небольших типов обычно эффективнее передавать по значению(если вы знакомы с C++, то можете рассматривать эту ситуацию как передачу аргумента в функцию по ссылке или по значению). Подробнее можете прочесть в [FAQ по Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers).

Пример:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Point struct {
    x, y int
}

func (self Point) SetX(v int) {
    self.x = v
}

func (self *Point) SetY(v int) {
    self.y = v
}

func main() {
    point := Point{1, 2}
    point.SetX(0)
    point.SetY(0)
    fmt.Println(point)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Y9Osy3IpQ4

Таким образом обычно следует отдать предпочтение ресиверу-указателю, если нет причин этого не делать. Эти причины перечислены опытными го-программистами [здесь](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-type) и далее я вольно переведу основные:

1. Не используйте ресивер-указатель для отображений, каналов и функций.
2. Не используйте ресивер-указатель для срезов, в которых не происходит перераспределение(reslice ) или реаллокация.
3. Если ресивер представляет собой структуру, содержащую мьютекс или другой подобный способ синхронизации - он должен быть указателем, для избежания копирования.

Comment: Я дополню ответ оставшимися при редактировании.